# image not displaying on HTML page

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am attempting to load two image files, using the ion-avatar tags from internal path and i've been trying to do so, using external google links and local path, but the image is not loading in either cases. I've been playing with the paths for a while and i still can't figure out whats wrong.

This is how i tried it in my HTML page

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let question of questions">
          <ion-avatar slot="start">
            <ion-img [src]="question.imageUrl"></ion-img>
          </ion-avatar>
```

my home.service.ts

```
     private questions: Questions[] = [
    {
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'quanto da 1+1?',
      imageUrl: 'img1.jpg',
      text:"Como faço pra calcular 1+1?",
      questions: ['local', 'endereço', 'horario']
    },
    {
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'vaga de emprego',
      imageUrl: 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Julio_Dantas.jpg',
      text:'Alguem sabe de uma vaga de emprego?',
      questions: ['vaga', 'experencia', 'salario']
    }
  ];
```

Where my images are locally
[image]

EDIT: i changed the links and it began to work properly, however my image and what is below the page is being now displayed as a scroll...

[image]

Comment: Inspect it in Developer console, see what is getting replaced in place of that, I mean what is being loaded in place of image, a string or what else

Comment: Your syntax is correct, you must look in dev console or Angury

Comment: Have you tried to put your image in the assets folder and link it like `imageUrl: 'assets/img1.jpg'`

Comment: i altered the links and it works now, however for some reason its now being displayed as a scrolling page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `[alt]` attribute to check if the image tag is loading or not. If it loads, that means there is an issue with the `[src]` path.